# dispatch response packet according to packet sequence id

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a third-part server, and I'm writing a dll interface for it, my clients use my dll to communicate with the server.

The protocol uses a long tcp connection, all traffic goes from this tcp connection. There could be sending/receiving multiple packets at the same time, like a `send_msg` and  `heart_beat` at same time, so I must use *async_write/async_read* to prevent blocking operation. Every packet has its sequence id. For example, I send a message with sequence id==123, then I should wait for server to respond a packet with sequence id==123.

**UPDATE**: There is no guarantee for the server to respond packet in order. If two packets sent in order of `A`, `B`, the response order could be `response_B`, `response_A`. The sequence id is the only way to identify the packet.

the packet looks like:

```
4bytes size   +   2 bytes crc check   +   4 bytes SEQUENCE ID   +   ....
```

The problem is that my clients who use my dll prefer using the functionalities in the blocking way, they don't like callbacks. For example, they like

```
bool DLL_EXPORT send_msg(...) {
   // send msg via long_connection, the seq_id==123
   // recv msg via long_connection, just want the packet with seq_id==123 (How?)
   return if_msg_sent_successfully;
}
```

I'm using boost asio, I don't know if there are any utility class of boost, or design patterns that suitable for this scenario, here is the solution I can come up with:

```
// use a global std::map<seq_id, packet_content>
std::map<int, std::string> map_received;
```

Everytime receives a packet, writes the `seq_id` and `packet_body` to the map_received, and the `send_msg` function looks like

```
bool DLL_EXPORT send_msg(...) {
   // async_send msg via long_connection, the seq_id==123
   while(not_time_out) {
       if(map_received.find(123) != map_received.end()) {
           // get the packet and erase the 123 pair
       }
       Sleep(10); // prevent cpu cost
   }
   return if_msg_sent_successfully;
}
```

This solution is ugly, there must be a better design for this. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `std::promise` and `std::future` (or their boost counterparts if your are not yet on C++11).

The idea is to store a `std::shared_ptr<std::promise<bool>>` with the current sequence id as a key in the map whenever a request is sent.
In the blocking send function you wait for the corresponding `std::future<bool>` to be set.
When a response packet is received, the corresponding `std::promise<bool>` is fetched from the map and the value is set and the sending function is "unblocked".

The following example is loosely based on the chat client example from the [Boost asio documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html) and is not complete (e.g. the connect part is missing, header and body reading is not split etc.). Since it is incomplete I did no runtime tests, but it should illustrate the idea.

```
#include <thread>
#include <map>
#include <future> 
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class Message
{
public:
  enum { header_length = 10 };
  enum { max_body_length = 512 };

  Message()
    : body_length_(0)
  {
  }

  const char* data() const
  {
    return data_;
  }

  char* data()
  {
    return data_;
  }

  std::size_t length() const
  {
    return header_length + body_length_;
  }

  const char* body() const
  {
    return data_ + header_length;
  }

  char* body()
  {
    return data_ + header_length;
  }

private:
  char data_[header_length + max_body_length];
  std::size_t body_length_;
};


class Client
{    
public:
    Client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : io_service(io_service),
          socket(io_service),
          current_sequence_id(0)
    {}

    bool blocking_send(const std::string& msg)
    {
        auto future = async_send(msg);
        // blocking wait
        return future.get();
    }

    void start_reading()
    {
        auto handler = [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
                       {
                           if(!ec)
                           {
                               // parse response ...
                               int response_id = 0;
                               auto promise = map_received[response_id];
                               promise->set_value(true);
                               map_received.erase(response_id);
                           }
                       };
        boost::asio::async_read(socket,
                                boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), Message::header_length),
                                handler);
    }

    void connect()
    {
        // ...
        start_reading();
    }

private:

    std::future<bool> async_send(const std::string& msg)
    {
        auto promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<bool>>();
        auto handler = [=](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/){std::cout << ec << std::endl;};
        boost::asio::async_write(socket,
                                 boost::asio::buffer(msg),
                                 handler);
        // store promise in map
        map_received[current_sequence_id] = promise;
        current_sequence_id++;
        return promise->get_future();
    }

    boost::asio::io_service& io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<std::promise<bool>>> map_received;
    int current_sequence_id;
    Message read_msg_;
};



int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    Client client(io_service);

    std::thread t([&io_service](){ io_service.run(); });

    client.connect();
    client.blocking_send("dummy1");
    client.blocking_send("dummy2");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Using std::promise as return value is very smart. This really helps a lot, Thank you m.s.

Comment: @aj3423 one additional note: since this only works if you use multiple threads, you must make sure that the access to `map_received` is serialized (e.g. using a mutex), as write-access to `std::map` is not thread-safe.

Comment: Yes I will use a mutex for multithreading, thanks for the tip m.s.